# Xaml Inherited StaticResource Styles

Tags: xaml

I am using Style Resources for my buttons.
Just wondering what is better to do.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <Button Content="Create Event" Click="CreateEvent_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavigationButton}" />
    <Button Content="Search Event" Click="SearchEvent_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavigationButton}" />
    <Button Content="My Events" Click="MyEvents_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavigationButton}" />
</StackPanel>
```

So, if I have many buttons I will need to write always Style="{StaticResource NavigationButton}"

Or to choose this one:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NavigationButton}" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Create Event" Click="CreateEvent_Click" />
    <Button Content="Search Event" Click="SearchEvent_Click" />
    <Button Content="My Events" Click="MyEvents_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to put the styling in the App.xaml under App Resources. This is a better solution then on page because the resource will only by created once (instead of on multiple pages when reused).

Also, you can specify a target type like the following. This way you will not have to reference a certain style the way you did in your example. You just define your style here:

```xml
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```